# Opening other reports from a report (Working in webplayer)

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Is there a way to open other dashboards/Reports ( saved in same server) from a report in web player.

I tried some python scripts which is used to access webpages but none of them is working in webplayer. My client want this to happen using buttons. So i prefer python scripts than HTML.

Much appreciated

Comment: Why not just use the URL with a button?

Comment: Could you explain how to do it please.I Tried some python scripts but its not working in webplayer

Comment: Sorry, i am not using html because of one more reason, i cannot change the web link based on a property in html, right?. I am changing web links to other reports based on document property.i were able to do this using python scripts. but it doesn't work in web player. i tried the method of changing html scripts using document property and python scripts. But document property is disappearing when i run this script

Answer (score 3):

1. Download an image of the button you want to use, like [this one](https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/youtube-play-button_318-41694.jpg).
2. Add this image to a text area. `Edit Text Area > Insert Image > (Select the downloaded image)`. Now you will see your "Button" image.
3. Edit the HTML and use href to the web page you care about. Notice the `src=` will already have your image name.

```html
<a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/TIBX,Spotfire,S,Products?ltr=1&bypass=true">
<img src="ff08c65b55ab4b36acd5dacc78f03eea.png" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: you can also do `<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')" />`

Comment: is there a way to change web address based on a document property drop down? like is select google in drop down it will get you google, but if you select yahoo it will get you to yahoo etc